# sequence of fields

Tags: galois-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Show that there exists a sequence of fields $F_i$ such that

(1) $L_0= \mathbb{Q}(i)$

(2) $L_{i+1}/L_i$ is a cyclic extension of degree $p$ for all $i \geq 0$.

(3) $L_n/\mathbb{Q}$ is a cyclic extension of degree $2p^n$ for all $n \geq 0$.

I have no idea whether i should find an explicit example of fields or i can prove its existence theoretically without giving concrete example, please help, thank you so much.

Comment: Is $\;x^p-2\in\Bbb Q(i)[x]\;$ irreducible?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to identify the field $L_k$ inside the field $K_k=\Bbb{Q}(i,\zeta_{k+1})$, where $\zeta_\ell=e^{2\pi i/p^\ell}.$

The Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(K_k/\Bbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $\Bbb{Z}_{4p^{k+1}}^*$, which you hopefully know the structure of.

Comment: Kronecker-Weber says that $L_n$ is necessarily (as an abelian extension of the rationals) a subfield of some cyclotomic field, so it is a matter of finding a manageable small one.